# How to easily spread a row of Qt widgets so that they are evenly spaced at all times?

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I've got a Qt window, and at the bottom of the window is a row of widgets (mostly buttons and checkboxes) for the user to interact with.

I want that row of widgets to look pretty (where "pretty" to me is defined as "evenly spaced" -- that is, no matter what width the user chooses for his window, the widgets in this row should always have an equal amount of space between them, and between the the leftmost and rightmost widgets and the edges of the window).

i.e. the row should look something like this (where XXX indicates a widget):

```
 [  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  ]
```

This appears easy enough to do  -- i.e. I can just do something like this:

```
 QBoxLayout * hbl = new QBoxLayout(Qt::LeftToRight, parentWidget);
 hbl->addStretch();
 hbl->addWidget(new QPushButton);
 hbl->addStretch();
 hbl->addWidget(new QPushButton);
 hbl->addStretch();
 hbl->addWidget(new QPushButton);
 [...]
 hbl->addStretch();
```

That works as long as all of the widgets are visible.

The problem is that sometimes I want to hide some of the widgets in the row, since they aren't relevant to the task at hand.

In that case, the remaining-visible widgets end up non-evenly spaced, because there's no way to hide the "stretch" items associated with the now-hidden buttons.

For example, if I was to hide the first and second widgets in the row shown above, then the remaining widgets end up looking like this:

```
 [      XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  ]
  ^^^^^^                  ^^
  too much space on the left!
```

Is there an easy way to get the behavior I want, or do I need to dive in to handling the implicit QSpacerItems explicitly?

Comment: Do not use `addSpasing()`. But instead just once set spacing for your layout item using function `void setSpacing(int)`.

Comment: Oops, those lines should have read `addStretch()`.  I'll fix it now.

Comment: Leave only the first and the last stretches and remove the rest.

Comment: @scopchanov that leaves all of the widgets pushed together at the horizontal-center of the row, rather than evenly-spaced along the entire width of the row.  (... which is not necessarily a bad thing; it's just not the look I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: I got it and I think further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Since `QBoxLayout` does not support changing the visibility of `QLayoutItem`, I would suggest you to do the folowing:

- remove and delete the stretch to the left of the widget being hidden by using [`QLayout::takeAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) like that:

  ```
    delete hbl->takeAt(ind - 1);
  ```
- insert a new stretch the the left of the widget being shown using [`QBoxLayout::insertStretch`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertStretch) like that:

  ```
    hbl->insertStretch(ind);
  ```

`ind` is the layout index of the widget being hidden/shown.

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        auto *widget = new QWidget(this);
        auto *hbl = new QHBoxLayout(widget);

        auto *btnLeft = new QPushButton(("Button"), widget);
        auto *btnRight = new QPushButton("Hide/Show", widget);

        hbl->addStretch();
        hbl->addWidget(btnLeft);
        hbl->addStretch();
        hbl->addWidget(new QPushButton("Unused", this));
        hbl->addStretch();
        hbl->addWidget(btnRight);
        hbl->addStretch();

        connect(btnRight, &QPushButton::clicked, [hbl, btnLeft](){
            int ind = 0;

            btnLeft->setVisible(!btnLeft->isVisible());

            for (int n = 0; n < hbl->count(); n++) {
                auto *w = hbl->itemAt(n)->widget();

                if (w && w == btnLeft)
                    ind = n;
            }

            if (btnLeft->isVisible())
                hbl->insertStretch(ind);
            else
                delete hbl->takeAt(ind - 1);
        });

        setCentralWidget(widget);
        resize(800, 600);
    }
};
```

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, did this work for you? I would be happy to hear your feedback.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I am happy to hear that and you are very welcome!